# Long.parseLong Error

Tags: java, string, parsing, binary, long-integer

I'm trying to Parse a potential Long value from a binary String, yet I still get an error when trying to do so.

```
public String func1(String B, String C, String D)
{
    long b = Long.parseLong(B, 2);
    long c = Long.parseLong(C, 2);
    long d = Long.parseLong(D, 2);

    String value = Long.toString((b & c) | (b & d), 2);
    return value;
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "1010101010101010101010101010101010101010/*....*/10101011"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Can anyone explain this?
Thanks!

Comment: Well how long is the actual string? (I assume it doesn't *actually* have `/*...*/` in?)

Comment: For testing purposes, the String is 32 bits long, but it can exceed that.

Comment: But have you actually verified that the string length is no longer than 64 (63 if the first character is 1), and that the characters are valid (zeros and ones, optional minus)?

Comment: Post a complete reproducible example

Comment: Your "test string" is already 48 bits long if you remove the `/*....*/`.

Comment: EDIT: The String was 64 bits in length.

Comment: And the error message actually contained `/*....*/`? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Right. So you had a value with 64 bits in, starting with 1. What value were you expecting `Long.parseLong` to return?

Answer (score 2):

A constant holding the maximum value a long can have, 2^63 - 1.

So, the last String which you can convert to Long with 2 radix is:
"111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"

If you will try parse value bigger than it, you will get java.lang.NumberFormatException